# SQL Server : whitespaces in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have this problem where in my database I get lots of empty spaces after my text,

In my email I have `"something@mail.com+_________________________________________"` lots of spaces

My email row is `nchar(255)`

and that is happening to all of my tables

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CHAR` and `NCHAR` will automatically right-pad a string with spaces to meet the defined length. Use `NVARCHAR(255)` instead of `NCHAR(255)`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use nvarchar

> SQL Server provides both datatypes to store character information. For the most part the two datatypes are identical in how you would work with them within SQL Server or from an application. The difference is that nvarchar is used to store unicode data, which is used to store multilingual data in your database tables. Other languages have an extended set of character codes that need to be saved and this datatype allows for this extension. If your database will not be storing multilingual data you should use the varchar datatype instead. The reason for this is that nvarchar takes twice as much space as varchar, this is because of the need to store the extended character codes for other languages from

Comment: You've explained the differences between varchar and nvarchar but not the differences between nchar and nvarchar.

Comment: @Blam the OP is using `nchar`. Halis suggested using `nvarchar` instead, then explained how `nvarchar` is different from `varchar`. If he's suggesting `nvarchar` vs. `nchar`, shouldn't the explanation describe how `nvarchar` differs from `nchar`???